# slice and remove every line that is lower than X character

Tags: php, arrays

I have a very simple question.

I have this list for example :

```
123456
123
123456
1234
```

And now, i want a simple php code to make an array from every every line, and then remove the line that has lower than 5 characters .

So i want this output :

```
123456
123456
```

How can we do it in PHP ?

Comment: [file()](http://php.net/file) [strlen()](http://php.net/strlen), and next time, try to find the functions you want yourself first: [function reference](http://php.net/manual/en/funcref.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your source is a file:

```
$lines = file( 'file.txt' );
foreach( $lines as $k => $line )
    if( mb_strlen( $line ) < 5 )
        unset( $lines[$k] );
print_r( $lines );
```

If the source is not a file, just ignore the first line, and use your variable with your "list" in the foreach.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) for this:

```
$input = array(
    "123456",
    "123",
    "123456",
    "1234",
);

$filteredInput = array_filter($input, function($item) {
   return strlen($item) >= 5; 
});
```